# PHP Deprecated: Optional parameter on PHP8.2 upgraded from PHP7

Tags: php, parameters, deprecated

I am getting following Deprecated error on php when i upgrade PHP version to 8.2

> Deprecated: Optional parameter $InitValue declared before required parameter $Parent is implicitly treated as a required parameter

```
function __construct($ControlType, $Name, $Caption, $DataType, $Format, $InitValue = "", &$Parent)
```

Any tips? greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to read what the exact error message is you get, but as far as I know optional parameters should be at the end. The [manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php): _"Note that any optional arguments should be specified after any required arguments, otherwise they cannot be omitted from calls."_.

Comment: Since you can't leave out arguments in the middle of the argument list, only at the end, it makes no sense to provide a default value for `$InitValue`. `$Parent` is required, and you have to give all the arguments before that.

Comment: I don't understand why moderators here are in so much rush to close questions without giving anyone a chance to give a proper explanation to the OP about the problem they're facing

Comment: @EyadBereh: A very understandable question when you regard Stack Overflow as a simple question & answer forum. However, it is not. Stack Overflow is a public platform building the definitive collection of coding questions & answers. Duplicate questions are not contributing to this. That's why these questions should be closed. I don't like it either, but it's how it is. I understand, you're writing an answer, and boom, closed. Happened to me many-many times.